# Why is gamma exposed through the square of spot prices?

Tags: options, gamma

As per this article, "the mathematically intuitive way to expose gamma is through the square of the underlying price": https://llllvvuu.dev/blog/unbundling-gamma

Can someone explain this? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dimensional analysis is the key:

The change in option price is in dollars. The change in option price is of course the sum of its changes (partial derivatives) with respect to its underlying risk factors. However you cannot add terms with different dimensions, that would literally be trying to add apples and oranges.

Let's look at delta, which (in finite difference notation) is $\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta S}$ where $S$ is the spot price. The contribution of delta to the change in option price is not delta, but "dollar delta", which is $\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta S} \Delta S$, because then the product is in the same units as the change in option price $\Delta C$.

Now Gamma is the second order change in the option price with respect to spot, which is $\frac{\Delta^2 C}{\Delta S^2}$. In order to be able to include this in the series that gives as sum the change in option price (units in dollars), the Gamma has to be multiplied by $\Delta S^2$. The product of the two $\frac{\Delta^2 C}{\Delta S^2} \Delta S^2$ is called "dollar gamma".

Summary: when adding quantities the quantities must have the same dimension in order for the sum to make sense.

Comment: Nicely explained, +1 Frido.

Comment: IMHO, dimensional analysis should be a cornerstone in any quant finance curriculum; just like they teach in physics.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Agree, it is a very simple and powerful principle, but still not part of standard curriculum. Just like I believe that 'truth tables' should be part of standard curriculum in real analysis / maths majors. It really helps understanding proofs (direct, contrapositive, and by contradiction).